# row with 1-2-3-4 ... in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a query that gives me the row 'x' like that :1-2-3-4 ...
not 3-4-5-6-7 ...

this is my query:

```
SELECT f1.`week`
    ,count(f2.`week`) AS X
    ,SUM(f2.inn) AS inn
    ,SUM(f2.`out`) AS `out`
FROM (  SELECT `week`
            ,SUM(IF(`etat` = 1,1,0)) AS inn
            ,SUM(IF(`etat` = 2,1,0)) AS `out` 
        FROM fait_stock 
        WHERE `week` BETWEEN 40 AND 51 
        GROUP BY `week`) AS f1 
JOIN (  SELECT `week`
            ,SUM(IF(`etat` = 1,1,0)) AS inn
            ,SUM(IF(`etat` = 2,1,0)) AS `out` 
        FROM fait_stock 
        WHERE `week` BETWEEN 1 AND 51 
        GROUP BY `week`) AS f2
    ON f2.`week` <= f1.`week` 
GROUP BY f1.`week`
```

this is the result :

[the result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBlKV.png)

Comment: Your query formatting makes it difficult to decipher. You might consider editing your question and placing your query in a code style block, with correct formatting. It would also be helpful to see the create statements for the tables you are using, and perhaps a few insert statements in order to determine if your joins, etc, are formulated correctly.

Comment: This looks like a data issue to me.  Are there three records in `fait_stock` where `\`week\` = 40`?

Comment: Provide test data for the tables and the expected output. You need this for yourself so let us see it as well. We can then easily check that any queries we create give the expected output on your test data. Include some ''awkward" test cases that you are having difficulties with.  It saves time for us as well as you. We normally need to see what the tables actually look like - not just the columns in the query.

Comment: it's me or you just want to make a rank from 1 in the col X ?